# Installing MySQL - Understanding initial message returned from MySQL

Tags: linux, mysql, centos

After MySQL is initially installed, it returns the message shown below the first time the daemon is started. I am trying to better understand this message, and have the following questions:

1. What causes the warning about the host not able to be looked up with resolveip?  This is a brand new install of Centos 6.4, then `yum install mysql mysql-server`.  MySQL server version is 5.1.69 Source distribution.
2. Why does it say `To start mysqld at boot time you have to copy support-files/mysql.server to the right place for your system`?  I thought I wanted to do `chkconfig --levels 235 mysqld on` to make MySQL start at boot time.
3. Why does it say `You can start the MySQL daemon with: cd /usr ; /usr/bin/mysqld_safe &`.  I thought I wanted to use `service mysqld start` or `/etc/init.d/mysqld start`.  What is different  between `mysqld` and `mysqld_safe`? What is the purpose of `cd /usr ;`? Also, what is the purpose of the `&`?
4. I tried to test the MySQL daemon using `mysql-test-run.pl`, but I don't seem to have `/usr/mysql-test`.  Any thoughts?

Thanks

```
[root@localhost Michael]# service mysqld start
Initializing MySQL database:  WARNING: The host 'localhost.mysite.com' could not be looked up with resolveip.
This probably means that your libc libraries are not 100 % compatible
with this binary MySQL version. The MySQL daemon, mysqld, should work
normally with the exception that host name resolving will not work.
This means that you should use IP addresses instead of hostnames
when specifying MySQL privileges !
Installing MySQL system tables...
OK
Filling help tables...
OK

To start mysqld at boot time you have to copy
support-files/mysql.server to the right place for your system

PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MySQL root USER !
To do so, start the server, then issue the following commands:

/usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password'
/usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root -h localhost.mysite.com password 'new-password'

Alternatively you can run:
/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation

which will also give you the option of removing the test
databases and anonymous user created by default.  This is
strongly recommended for production servers.

See the manual for more instructions.

You can start the MySQL daemon with:
cd /usr ; /usr/bin/mysqld_safe &

You can test the MySQL daemon with mysql-test-run.pl
cd /usr/mysql-test ; perl mysql-test-run.pl

Please report any problems with the /usr/bin/mysqlbug script!

                                                           [  OK  ]
Starting mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
[root@localhost Michael]#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Usually those warnings are related to compiled binaries compatibilities and your installed C libraries. CentOS 6.X come with a new C library version which could cause some warning on particular software versions like mysql 5.1.69.
2. mysql installer generates a init script for you called mysql.server, basically what you have to is (make sure you are using the right binary and not installing the source code instead):

   sudo cp support-files/mysql.server /etc/init.d/mysql

   chmod 755 /etc/init.d/mysql

   chkconfig --add mysql

   chkconfig --levels 235 mysql
3. The `/usr/bin/mysqld_safe &` script is the one that runs up mysql server. If you take a look to mysql init script you will see the script is responsible of passing the right parameters to mysql_safe script to manage your mysql database service. Those parameters of course can be read from my.cnf config file or using the command line. Also, if you have follow mysql install recommendations, at this point you should be able to start the service as you mention before using: `/etc/init.d/mysqld {start|stop|restart}`
4. For this one, you simply have to check mysql installation path. If you compiled mysql from `mysql-XXXXX.tar.gz` file then you will be able to locate the script on mysql installation path directory mysql-test. If installed using yum, then try using mysqltest command usually at `/usr/bin/mysqltest`

Comment: Thanks mdiianni,  #2 I don't seem to have a mysql.server script. #3.  What is the purpose of the `&`?

Comment: The script should be available on mysql installation path or you could easily get a copy on MySQL website for your mysql version. The `&` is a linux standard command to run processes on the background. E.g. program [arguments] &